# Fakeiteasy method not being called. errors on MustHaveHappened assertion

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

New in using FakeItEasy. I'm getting error at

```
            A.CallTo(() => Lister.GetResult(A<int>._, A<int>._)).MustHaveHappened();
```

so I guess this

```
            A.CallTo(() => Lister
                .GetResult(A<int>._, A<int>._))
                .Returns(new ResponseList(1, new List<RecordsValues>())) ;
```

is not being triggered. When I removed the .MustHaveHappened assertion, the test proceeds, also getting 200 statuscode (a controller is in test). It passes on the 2nd code snippet above but throws no error.

Any advice is appreciated.

Test

```
    public class GetByListTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void GetByList_GetFieldsByRange_Test()
        {
            ILister Lister = A.Fake<ILister>();
            IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory = A.Fake<IDbConnectionFactory>();
            GetByList GetByList = new(dbConnectionFactory);

            A.CallTo(() => Lister
                .GetResult(A<int>._, A<int>._))
                .Returns(new ResponseList(1, new List<RecordsValues>()));
            
            //result contains empty and 0 values, with 200 statuscode
            //result it does not contain the expected return declared on the above callTo return
            var result = (OkObjectResult)GetByList.GetFieldsByRange();


            //if I remove this, the test passes but with incorrect result value, so I assume it really is not being called as when I add the line below, it errs out
            A.CallTo(() => Lister.GetResult(A<int>._, A<int>._)).MustHaveHappened();
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal(200, result.StatusCode);


        }
    }
```

Endpoint

```
        private readonly ILister Lister;

        public GetByList(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
        {
            DataService securityProjectDataService = new(dbConnectionFactory);
            Lister = new SecurityProjectLister(DataService);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetFieldsByRange([FromQuery][Range(0, int.MaxValue)] int skip = 0, [FromQuery][Range(0, 1000)] int top = 1000)
        {
            ResponseList response = securityProjectLister.GetResult(skip, top);
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

If I lack something, please point out. I'm happy to take any learnings.
Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Did you mean FakeItEasy, not TakeItEasy, right?

Comment: Yes, guess I shuffled it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you are never actually *using* the `ILister` fake.

The fake you have created resides inside your test method,

```
ILister Lister = A.Fake<ILister>();
```

whereas you create a separate `ILister` object in your endpoint class:

```
Lister = new SecurityProjectLister(DataService);
```

In order to actually benefit from your `ILister` fake, you need dependency injection of an `ILister` object in your enpoint class.

As it currently stands, I find your endpoint class snippet a little difficult to understand. I believe some names have been mixed up, so that the current implementation:

```csharp
private readonly ILister Lister;

public GetByList(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
{
    DataService securityProjectDataService = new(dbConnectionFactory);
    Lister = new SecurityProjectLister(DataService);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFieldsByRange(...)
{
    ResponseList response = securityProjectLister.GetResult(skip, top);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

should in fact be this:

```csharp
private readonly ILister securityProjectLister; // EDITED

public GetByList(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
{
    DataService securityProjectDataService = new(dbConnectionFactory);
    securityProjectLister = new SecurityProjectLister(securityProjectDataService); // EDITED
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFieldsByRange(...)
{
    // Now, your ILister object is used here:
    ResponseList response = securityProjectLister.GetResult(skip, top);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

If this is the case, I actually believe you will need to extract the creation of both the `DataService` object and the `ILister` object to outside of your endpoint class, and provide your endpoint class constructor with an `ILister` object.

I believe a possible implementation could be similar to the following:

Endpoint class snippet:

```csharp
private readonly ILister securityProjectLister;

public GetByList(ILister lister)
{
    securityProjectLister = lister;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFieldsByRange(...)
{
    // Remains unchanged
}
```

Test method:

```csharp
public void GetByList_GetFieldsByRange_Test()
{
    IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory = A.Fake<IDbConnectionFactory>();

    DataService securityProjectDataService = new(dbConnectionFactory);
    ILister Lister = new SecurityProjectLister(securityProjectDataService);

    GetByList GetByList = new(Lister);

    // Unchanged:
    A.CallTo(() => Lister
        .GetResult(A<int>._, A<int>._))
        .Returns(new ResponseList(1, new List<RecordsValues>()));
    
    // The remaining code remains unchanged
}
```

Now, the `GetByList` object is using the very `ILister` object on which you have configured `A.CallTo(...).Returns(...);` in your test method.

Comment: You pointed out a lot and will try those out. By just looking at it Im getting the sense that it would work out that way. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully it will work out! Glad to be able to provide some insight :)